# SpringBoot DTO + JPA with List<T> property

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, dto

Let say I have the following entity, (I skip the constructor for simplicity):

```
public class Person {
    int id;
    String name;
    String lastName;
    Date birthday;
    List<Vehicles> vehicles;
}
```

And I want to create a DTO in order to get only what I need from the DB:

```
public class PersonDTO {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<Vehicles> vehicles;
}
```

My Crud repository looks like this:

```
Person findById(int personId);
```

But I want to change it to:

```
PersonDTO findById(int personId);
```

It works perfectly if I remove the **vehicles** property, (is a List), but I do need this list. Any clue?

Comment: The purpose of a DTO is for _data transfer_. Transform the representation in your controller (and you should probably also use `@JsonIdentityInfo` to avoid nesting the `vehicles` entity). A tool like MapStruct is very helpful here. (Note: Also use `LocalDate` for something like a birthday.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data DTO projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388363/spring-data-dto-projection) tl;dr; nested properties are not allowed

Comment: Want to more details to answer this question. Are they any errors occurred with this and want are the spring JPA annotations that using.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj if I change List<Vehicles> by Vehicles it works. When you said nested property, do you mean a List<>?

Comment: You can't use nested properties in DTO as @RobertNiestroj said. Although if you really do need the list in your DTO you'll have to use either MapperFactory or you can Manually call the List setter method and get the list from Person and set the list like:
`personDto.setVehicles(person.getVehicles);`

Answer (score 2):

Citing the [Spring Data JPA reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos):

> Another way of defining projections is by using value type DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) that hold properties for the fields that are supposed to be retrieved. These DTO types can be used in exactly the same way projection interfaces are used, except that no proxying happens and **no nested projections can be applied**.

Your `List<Vehicles> vehicles` is a nested projection, so your apporach is not applicable. You need to make use of an [interface-based projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) in this case:

```
public interface PersonProjection {

    int getId();

    String getName();

    List<VehicleProjection> getVehicles();

    interface VehicleProjection {

        // Getters for desired fields of Vehicle as above for Person(Projection)

    }

}
```

Then you can change your repository method to

```
PersonProjection findById(int personId);
```

Unfortunately, the interface-based approach is slightly less performant because, as the reference documentation states, proxying happens.

Comment: if Vehicles are stored as jsonb then above interface projection approach doesn't work